# Facebook Mediation for Android DFP SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, google-dfp, facebook-audience-network

I integrated Facebook Audience Network and Facebook Adapter from here: https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.facebook#read

Then as it's in the instructions on the link I used this code to set up the PublisherAdView. (cube3 is a banner)

```
Bundle extras = new FacebookAdapter.FacebookExtrasBundleBuilder()
    .setNativeAdChoicesIconExpandable(false)
    .build();
cube3= (PublisherAdView) findViewById(R.id.cube3);
PublisherAdRequest cubeRequest3 = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(FacebookAdapter.class, extras)
            .build();
cube3.loadAd(cubeRequest3);
cube3.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
            cube3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.v("FAILED", "TO LOAD@@");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            cube3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

But the Ad Mediation isn't working. 
In the log I am getting:

> W/FacebookAdapter: (#200) Permissions error
>
> I/Ads: No fill from any mediation ad networks.
>
> FAILED: TO LOAD@@ (which I set up in the code to appear if not loaded)

How to make the mediation work?

---

Update:
So I added the AdSettings. addTestDevice("HASH"); code, and now the test ad is appearing saying Your Ad Integration works and the log is saying that the impression is being logged. However on the facebook audience panel there are still no registered impressions so I can't approve the app. What do I need to do for facebook to register the impressions?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I found the solution, for some reason using the admin account in the facebook application caused the permission error. I added another account as tester, and used it in the Facebook application, and it worked, my app is now in review.

Comment: Hi @Hichaam I am testing that approach now...added the account as tester and logged in Facebook. Have you used the ads with Test Device or got the regular ads right away? Also how long does it take for Facebook to notice impressions? Thank you for your response!

Comment: No, you should remove your device from test devices, if you need call clearTestDevices to be sure. The adds did't appear, but in the log the request was successful, and instantly in Facebook I could submit the app to review. If you have issues, try to uninstall Facebook and reinstall it

Comment: And as a remark, you should move the call to addListener above loadAd

Comment: Hi Hichaam thanks for your response!
So, I am still getting the #200 permission error when logged in Facebook app with a Facebook account which is added as Tester. And the log is saying I should add the AdSettings.addTestDevice() thing with my hash in order for it to work. Now when I add that I get the Test ad and the log says the impression is logged but on Facebook nothing happens. I uninstalled and installed the facebook app and still nothing. And cleared the test devices. Have you used Test User or Tester account when you got it to work?

Comment: I refer this one https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start and Integrate PublisherAdview(BannerAd) with facebook mediation. And I added implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.0.0.0'dependencies on build.gradle(app) refer from https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/mediation/facebook. But still can't get ad from facebook even sample ad also. I don't know how to debug and get ad, but same working fine on iOS platform, Can you guide me?